# Data servers: Do query optimisers re-write queries removing redundant columns during the plan creation?

Tags: query-performance, optimization, view, architecture, reporting

Although I'm using SQL Server, as this is a question of whether an optimiser will re-write a query to remove redundant columns, I'm pitching this at all data servers: RDBMS, NoSQL, MPP, anything capable of holding and querying stored data using SQL that shall optimise the query before running it.

I kinda feel that they would, or at least it would seem logical that they would especially as it'd be crazy to fill a cache unnecessarily, but I can't find any evidence to say they would.

I don't want to get bogged-down on how environments, network, server, table, and cache loads, and table size and performance will alter the selected plans; this is just a very high-level question of: would the server rewrite a query to remove redundant columns and/or joins, but mostly columns, that are not in any way used to generate the result.

On my isolated dev server, I have this test query running against a tiny test 290k row table, it has a pk on an identity field, and a composite index which whilst two of the fields from the derived table are covered as part of the index, the primary field under test is not

The derived table in this instance has 7 redundant columns, and I'm executing these three DBCC commands before each run so as to start with a cold cache : `DBCC FreeProcCache; DBCC DropCleanBuffers; DBCC FreeSystemCache('sql plans')`:

```
Select
a.provider_type
,Count(1) As count_of_provider_type

From (
    Select
    customer_id
    ,access_plan
    ,provider_type
    ,ap_postcode
    ,browser
    ,session_start_date
    ,session_end_date
    ,payment_method

    From adhoc..datacentre

)a

Group By
a.provider_type;
```

Returns this actual plan:
[image]

And from the profiler, CPU: 92, Reads: 23703

And then, having re-ran the three DBCC commands to return the cache to cold, running this re-expressed query:

```
Select
provider_type
,Count(1) As count_of_provider_type

From adhoc..datacentre

Group By provider_type;
```

Gives me this actual plan:
[image]

And profiler, CPU: 78, Reads: 23476

Notice any similarities?
Which given the batch count, io and cpu, leads me to wonder that the optimiser did rewrite the first query to remove the derived table and the redundant columns.

But how can I prove it.
I can't find anything at learn.microsoft under the Query Processing Architecture to suggest that the optimiser would rewrite the query, neither can I find a way of seeing what was transferred to cache.
Does anything exist that can definitively say exactly what was read and cached.

Remember - although I'm using SQL Server, I'd be interested to know how other RDBMS / MPP such as GBQ, Redshift, Athena, Snowflake etc would handle this

And finally, the why.
What nutjob would write the first query without having realised it could be re-expressed?

This is twofold: Firstly views, and secondly and more prominently: SQL from visualisation and reporting tools capable of accepting an SQL script, which is often functionally equivalent to a non-materialised view.

As we all know, views can be abused. They shouldn't, and in an ideal world, users would create views as isolated models to spit-out a result-set ready for ingestion by the tool that the model was designed for, which is also the same direction for visualisation and reporting tools.

But we all know this never happens.
Just like a doctor who has a cream for that, so too have engineering built a view that includes "what you're after" in its output, "so you don't need to go and create a new query, just query that view".
And if the view is basic enough, maybe it's being used to replace a table, but includes scd:2 logic, and maybe its selecting non-engineering and/or PII data; or maybe it is a basic model with a couple of non-complex joins.
But if a user were to query this view for only a couple of fields, would the optimiser rewrite the query to remove redundant columns of a single-table view, and possibly remove redundant joins from a multi-table view?

As I said at the beginning, I feel the optimizer would, but I need to be able to evidence this beyond conjecture or theory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Typically, an optimiser will drop unnecessary columns, and will also drop joins if possible.

The most obvious case of dropping columns is where `*` is used to select all columns at an earlier stage (in a derived table, or CTE), but not all columns are retained at the final output.

In some cases, the inclusion of unused columns may be a small programming error, but unused columns also frequently remain in intermediary results for the purpose of debugging, or (as you've already said) because the same intermediary results are shared between a number of outputs, some of which use certain columns that others don't.

Also worth remembering that SQL is designed to support ad-hoc use, where a programmer may be iterating quickly through several forms of a query with minor variations, quickly re-adapting existing skeletons, or otherwise dealing with scraps of code which aren't intended to become permanent fixtures, so the fact that the optimiser makes the easy optimisations rather than complaining that an unnecessary column is an error, is a desirable feature.

Comment: I thought this to be the case, but where is this evidenced? Is there any way the optimised query / algebrized version can be seen, or any books/whitepaper's where this is discussed.
The honesty box behind this is that I'm also a Tableau developer. Tableau have a function for dropping a query into a "Custom SQL" object, and depending on what you are doing, will send the top query.
The common consensus is that cSQL should be avoided as it is underperforming due to the presence of the derived table.
I've called this out having tested and demonstrated this to be factually incorrect but...

Comment: ... despite this, there are those including engineers within Tableau that refuse to listen, arguing using untested ideas that the entirety of the derived table is always executed. One such example comes from this whitepaper who is using Select * which I suspect to be an effort to force the theory to fit a conclusion: https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Best-Practices-for-Using-Tableau-With-Snowflake.pdf
...

Comment: ... 
Page 8-12 for example.
Which in turn references a tiny unevidenced entry on pg 39 of the "Designing Efficient Workbooks" by Interworks - I have a copy here: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AljLJsyUbXmPhIwEMmT2oFK1p-Tfqg?e=4WLxSx

So in order to back this up I need to identify hard-proof that this is the case as right now, there is far too much confusion, but most of these articles seem to be written by those who assume queries will be executed exactly as they are written, and just like a book, the longer the query, the more time and resource it'll take to process

Comment: @SteveMartin, I must admit I've spent a few minutes searching and it's difficult to find an authoritative statement that the disregard of unused columns is an optimisation SQL Server is capable of. The most straightforward kind of proof however is exactly what you've already done: show that the query plan or execution time changes depending on whether a column contributes to the final result or not (using two queries that select multiple columns in an intermediary step, but differ only by whether the output selects all columns from the intermediary step or not).

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I guessed as much, although is this the case with other vendors? I was thinking Oracle and Postgres more than anything, especially Oracle given its wide-range of optimisation options, but still I'm drawing a blank.
It would seem illogical that despite the query enhancements, that an optimiser would leave redundant items in and then pull those through only to be ditched a second or so later, the waste on resource would be objectional

Comment: @SteveMartin, in my understanding, the existence of this optimisation is common to all major SQL engines. A main point of SQL engines is to devise the most efficient query plans and maximise the systemic performance of the hardware, so there'd be no reason not to implement this straightforward optimisation.

Comment: Thank @Steve, yes this is my understanding too, and is often taught and spoken of in major forums such as SQLBits, and it'd be crazy to think that platforms spend millions on algorithm development, yet retain redundant columns and joins. But I just can't prove it, I have no reference material or evidence to explicitly say that this is exactly what happens, and without this, article writers will continue to make unverified claims of the inverse.

Comment: @SteveMartin, you can prove it, we've already established that, we just can't find reference material which explicitly says so. I happen to know SQLite (as an example of a different and open source SQL engine) does have documentation that strongly implies this behaviour, under heading *"17. The Omit OUTER JOIN Optimization"*: https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html. There are other subtle references, example: https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/baa5bb76c35a124c. However, if you're arguing with people who doubt this behaviour in the first place, it can be very difficult to marshal clear evidence.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I'll look into those sources.
It occurred to me to run the query for the derived table which might be able to provide some more conclusive evidence. Back to my above screen shots, the estimated row size for both is 25B, but when running for the derived table, the row size jumped to 189B, which surely must be evidence to say that the amount of data per row is increasing due to the presence of more columns being used to build a row

Comment: @SteveMartin, that logic seems sound to me. If you actually look at the "output" list at the bottom of your screenshots, it is clear that in both cases the only output of the scan is the `provider_type` column. As there are no other relevant operators in the plan to consider, then that is already conclusive evidence that the unused columns mentioned in the query, are not being fetched from storage. I don't see why you would need more evidence, or what alternative explanation would be in play (other than the explanation that the optimiser excludes columns because they are unused).

Comment: I had wondered on that @Steve, but had disregarded as this is a final selection of data heading to the aggregation, it doesn't show which columns were used to build the result which is what I'm trying to prove. It'd be nice if the plan said something like "some doofus asked for more columns than necessary, so I re-wrote the query to disregard the mindlessness, and this is what I came up with" Or something like that :)

Comment: @SteveMartin, the index scan is the very first operation in the pipeline, and the column is already absent. You would see from inspecting all other operators that there is no involvement of the unused columns listed in the original query.